# Troubleshooting YII logout issue?

Tags: yii

I select the "remember me" checkbox when I log in, and I check in the code that this is excecuted:

```
if($this->_identity->errorCode===UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE) {
  $duration= 3600*24*30; // 30 days
  Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity,$duration);
  return true;
}
```

So I am setting this. However, if I leave my browser and come back, i am logged out. Any ideas as to what I can look at that could be causing this?

Comment: Are you using Chrome? Open up developer tools and go to the resources tab. In the left menu, can you see a cookie being set (under cookies) for your site?

Comment: I see loads of cookies being set? Is there a specific one I must look for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set allowAutoLogin in your config/main.php file to allow cookie-based login

```
   'components' => array(
        'user'=>array(
            // enable cookie-based authentication
            'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
            ...
        ),
    ...
```